# Audio Not Outputting Through 3.5mm Port

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headset

I can get audio to output using my laptop's internal speakers, or a USB-based headset just fine. However, whenever I plug a device into the 3.5mm port on my computer, it doesn't output audio and only makes a faint, repeated popping sound.

I have verified that the headset I'm attempting to use does work, using both my phone and a Windows install on the same laptop. In both cases, it worked just fine. I also used to previously work on my Ubuntu install (18.04.3).

According to AlsaMixer, my card is an HDA Intel PCH and my chip is a Realtek ALC295; with automute disabled. I've tried rebooting, uninstalling and reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio, and resetting alsa's settings. I've also tried an assortment of commands and configuration edits from top-rated answers in other questions.

My laptop detects the headset just fine, and appears to be outputting the audio to the headset (the little output volume bar seems accurate), but the audio never arrives at my headset for reasons I can't figure out.

Answer (score 1):

First install the package PulseAudio Volume Control.

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

Then open it, you see Output Devices Tab.

[image: pavucontrol]

My case, this computer doesn't have a lineout cable plugged in, for now.
And when you want to change between a headset and line-out speakers by keyboard, you can set global shortcuts on the System Settings.

[image: shortcuts]

Two new shortcuts 'line' and 'headphone'
To switch Lineout

```
 pactl set-sink-port *sinknumber* analog-output-lineout
```

To Headphones

```
pactl set-sink-port *sinknumber* analog-output-headphones
```

The *sinknumber* is shown by the command on the terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T).

```
pactl list sinks | egrep -A2 "Port|Sink"
```

Then it tells where the analog outputs are.

```
Sink #0
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_output.usb-VIA_Technologies_Inc._NFJ_USB_Audio-00.iec958-stereo
--
    Ports:
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority: 0)
    Active Port: iec958-stereo-output
    Formats:
        pcm
--
Sink #1
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
--
    Ports:
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority: 9900, not available)
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority: 10000, not available)
--
    Active Port: analog-output-lineout
    Formats:
```

My case it is on Sink #1 and I set the shortcut command for lineout:

```
 pactl set-sink-port 1 analog-output-lineout
```

Comment: Even after switching the output over using the pavucontrol; I'm still not getting any audio output through the port.

Comment: Use live Ubuntu 16.04 to do the same thing and if only 18.04.3 fails then it must have some bugs.

Comment: Tested using Ubuntu 16.04 live disk, same effect.

Comment: Then it would be some bugs. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/529619/realtek-alc295-hp-spectre-laptop-headphones-play-audio-in-windows-but-dont-p