# Ubuntu doesn't let me switch between headphones and line out

Tags: gnome, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control

I'm using ubuntu 20.04. I've tried switching from line out to headphones from settings and pavucontrol. Neither works. I've a 4.0 surround sound system on line out, but I've tried stereo and that doesn't work either. Headphones are stereo. Can you help me?

When I connect my stereo speakers to my headphone jack. Can't connect 4.0 there, because it needs 2 jacks. Sounds work on speaker, but not on headphones connected to line out. When I switch output devices.

`pactl list sinks` gives me-

```
Sink #0
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_0c_00.3.analog-stereo
    Description: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 9
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 79581 / 121% / 5.06 dB,   front-right: 79581 / 121% / 5.06 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_0c_00.3.analog-stereo.monitor
    Latency: 26672 usec, configured 26000 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "ALC1220 Analog"
        alsa.id = "ALC1220 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "3"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xef800000 irq 77"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:0c:00.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/sound/card3"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.product.id = "1457"
        device.product.name = "Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller"
        device.string = "front:3"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352768"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176384"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Ports:
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority: 9000, available)
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9900, available)
    Active Port: analog-output-headphones
    Formats:
        pcm

Sink #1
    State: RUNNING
    Name: PulseEffects_apps
    Description: PulseEffects(apps)
    Driver: module-null-sink.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 29
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor Source: PulseEffects_apps.monitor
    Latency: 30 usec, configured 10000 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY SET_FORMATS 
    Properties:
        device.description = "PulseEffects(apps)"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
    Formats:
        pcm

Sink #2
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: PulseEffects_mic
    Description: PulseEffects(mic)
    Driver: module-null-sink.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 30
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    Monitor Source: PulseEffects_mic.monitor
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY SET_FORMATS 
    Properties:
        device.description = "PulseEffects(mic)"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
    Formats:
        pcm
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, could you put the output of `pactl list sinks`? And tell us what happens when you plug a 4.0 surround system into headphone jack?

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka, I've made the edit. Thanks for your response!

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for, but I can tell you many ways to get pseudo 4 channel surround. 1. Buy a USB DAC (digital output is a way better sound quality). 2. split stereo analog output cable into two. 3. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379735/how-to-output-stereo-sound-on-multiple-channels-of-a-surround-output) does play headphone and lineout at the same time. Only the option #1 is practical to me.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka, I have an msi x399 motherboard. I probably don't need a DAC. I want the ability to switch between the two audio devices when I want to. Not to play both at the same time... I feel it's a software issue. Device switching works perfectly on windows.

Comment: If the audio is for not about music or movie, you don't need a USB DAC thing. Now I got what you want. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192366/audio-not-outputting-through-3-5mm-port/1192409#1192409